# Convert old silverstripe form to SS 3

Tags: silverstripe

I have an old SS2.4 site which I have updated to SS3.1.13.  The only part of the old site I can't get working is a search form that filters DataObjects. The old code is:

```
public function doCollectionSearch($data, $form)
{
    $filters = array();
    ...
    //setup some filters based on user selections
    ...
    $where = implode(" AND ", $filters);

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['start'])) $_REQUEST['start'] = 0;
    $limit = $_REQUEST['start'].",50";

    return $this->customise(array(
        'Collections' => DataObject::get("Collection", $where, "Genus, Species ASC", null, $limit)
    ))->renderWith(array('Collection_results','Page'));
}
```

I have updated the last part to:

```
    return $this->customise(array(
        'Collections' => Collection::get()->where($where)->sort("Genus, Species ASC")->limit($limit)
    ))->renderWith(array('Collection_results','Page'));
```

But I get a "the method 'fortemplate' does not exist on 'CollectionPage_Controller'".

I know the $where is not right yet, but if I strip that out I still get an error..

I know I am missing something obvious...can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get that error if your template accesses a method or database field that returns an object that can't be reduced to a string. This often happens when you have a related object (say a parent page) and you do something like the following:

```
<p>My parent is: $Parent</p>
```

Instead of

```
<p>My parent is: $Parent.Title</p>
```

The same thing existed in 2.4 so this doesn't totally explain your problem, but I'd look for something like the above scenario in your templates.